# How to stop nomencl using the page headers of the previous section

Tags: header-footer, nomenclature

In this example the second page of the nomenclature is entitled list of tables, inheriting it's title from the previous section. How do I change the title of the second page to nomenclature?

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}        
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\listoftables
\printnomenclature  

\mainmatter % book mode only

\chapter{Introduction}
Introduction

\nomenclature[]{FOO1}{bar1}
\nomenclature[]{FOO2}{bar2}
\nomenclature[]{FOO3}{bar3}
\nomenclature[]{FOO4}{bar4}
\nomenclature[]{FOO5}{bar5}
\nomenclature[]{FOO6}{bar6}
\nomenclature[]{FOO7}{bar7}
\nomenclature[]{FOO8}{bar8}
\nomenclature[]{FOO9}{bar9}
\nomenclature[]{FOO10}{bar10}
\nomenclature[]{FOO11}{bar11}
\nomenclature[]{FOO12}{bar12}
\nomenclature[]{FOO13}{bar13}
\nomenclature[]{FOO14}{bar14}
\nomenclature[]{FOO15}{bar15}
\nomenclature[]{FOO16}{bar16}
\nomenclature[]{FOO17}{bar17}
\nomenclature[]{FOO18}{bar18}
\nomenclature[]{FOO19}{bar19}
\nomenclature[]{FOO20}{bar20}
\nomenclature[]{FOO21}{bar21}
\nomenclature[]{FOO22}{bar22}
\nomenclature[]{FOO23}{bar23}
\nomenclature[]{FOO24}{bar24}
\nomenclature[]{FOO25}{bar25}
\nomenclature[]{FOO26}{bar26}
\nomenclature[]{FOO27}{bar27}
\nomenclature[]{FOO28}{bar28}
\nomenclature[]{FOO29}{bar29}
\nomenclature[]{FOO30}{bar30}

\end{document}
```

I compile my thesis with make, but compiling it with this oneliner compiles the example and replicates the problem

```
pdflatex ProblemNomenclature.tex && makeindex ProblemNomenclature.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o ProblemNomenclature.nls && pdflatex ProblemNomenclature.tex
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add these to your document:

```
\cleardoublepage           
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols} %% may be this is good.
\markboth{\MakeUppercase\nomname}{\MakeUppercase\nomname}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage  
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols} %% may be this is good.
\markboth{\MakeUppercase\nomname}{\MakeUppercase\nomname}  
\printnomenclature

\mainmatter % book mode only

\chapter{Introduction}
Introduction

\nomenclature[]{FOO1}{bar1}
\nomenclature[]{FOO2}{bar2}
\nomenclature[]{FOO3}{bar3}
\nomenclature[]{FOO4}{bar4}
\nomenclature[]{FOO5}{bar5}
\nomenclature[]{FOO6}{bar6}
\nomenclature[]{FOO7}{bar7}
\nomenclature[]{FOO8}{bar8}
\nomenclature[]{FOO9}{bar9}
\nomenclature[]{FOO10}{bar10}
\nomenclature[]{FOO11}{bar11}
\nomenclature[]{FOO12}{bar12}
\nomenclature[]{FOO13}{bar13}
\nomenclature[]{FOO14}{bar14}
\nomenclature[]{FOO15}{bar15}
\nomenclature[]{FOO16}{bar16}
\nomenclature[]{FOO17}{bar17}
\nomenclature[]{FOO18}{bar18}
\nomenclature[]{FOO19}{bar19}
\nomenclature[]{FOO20}{bar20}
\nomenclature[]{FOO21}{bar21}
\nomenclature[]{FOO22}{bar22}
\nomenclature[]{FOO23}{bar23}
\nomenclature[]{FOO24}{bar24}
\nomenclature[]{FOO25}{bar25}
\nomenclature[]{FOO26}{bar26}
\nomenclature[]{FOO27}{bar27}
\nomenclature[]{FOO28}{bar28}
\nomenclature[]{FOO29}{bar29}
\nomenclature[]{FOO30}{bar30}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notes:

- If you want to retain the heading `Nomenclature`, comment the line `\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}`.

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly, and I think that you may be the author of the class file that I am using. If that is true, thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing is to modify how `nomencl` defines the chapter heading. I have also called the `arara` statements that avoid that complicated command line, so that you can simply issue

```
arara ProblemNomenclature.tex
```

Here's the code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
\makenomenclature

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}
  {\chapter*{\nomname}}% usually only \chapter*{\nomname} is issued
  {\chapter*{\nomname}\markboth{\MakeUppercase\nomname}{\MakeUppercase\nomname}}
  {}{}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\listoftables

\printnomenclature

\mainmatter % book mode only

\chapter{Introduction}
Introduction

...
```

[image]